# OpenVZ container as gateway performance issue?

Tags: linux, virtualization, performance, gateway, openvz

I am running a lot of openvz container in server. Now I have a lot of performance issue, and I think they come from I/O since munin graph show a lot of I/O activiy.

Server is proxmox, and it was recently upgraded (this could be the problem also)
But near upgrade to last version of proxmox I added a gateway in a container running shorewall.

But now is almost impossible to log in the server, rebooting makes the system usuable but after two or tree hours I/O problems come again.

There isnt too much network activiy (10kb/s) it's  a home "test" server.

Any other idea in order to detect the problem? openvz container asgateway is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch back to kernel 2.6.18 and the I/O problem went away. It seems a problem with kernel 2.6.24

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the "failctl" column by typing this command :

```
vzctl exec 101 cat /proc/user_beancounters
```

You now need to adapt (101 here) this number to all of your VMs. If some beancounters are not equal to 0, you need to increase those value.

Now for example, if you want to grow a value on the fly, you could do like this :

```
vzctl set 101 --privvmpages 786432:1048576 --save --setmod restart
```

Now, for your I/O poblems, on the main machine (hosting VMs), is a "top" commands is giving you some iowaits ? If it's the case, it means you should add more disks.

Comment: yes, at hardware node there was a problem with a process using %100 cpu. I now change the kernel, but not sure if this would fix the problem since is like random

Comment: Did you try to upgrade to the last version of proxmox ?

Comment: the problem started after upgrade to last version (1.5)

Comment: Did you look at beancounters like I told you ?